# How do I get an integer from an string array in google maps API?

Tags: javascript, api, maps

This google maps api 'for loop' returns the duration of a journey as a string (the last line return "34 min" in this example).

```
for (var i = 0; i < originList.length; i++) {
  var results = response.rows[i].elements;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': originList[i]
  },
  showGeocodedAddressOnMap(false));
    for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': destinationList[j]
      },
      showGeocodedAddressOnMap(true));
      outputDiv.innerHTML += originList[i] + ' to ' + destinationList[j] + ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in ' + results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a chance I can get only numerical values from `results[j].duration.text;` and use them as integers? The final goal is to use the duration in a simple `S = V/t` formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro the .text will give human readable output (includes unit of measurement), but the values are in .value.

So `results[j].duration.value` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out JavaScript's `parseInt` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Try doing `parseInt(results[j].duration.text)` that should extract only the integer value for you. There is also `parseFloat` if you want a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys!

I tried with result[j].duration.value but it seems to return values which do not correspond to the truth.

I solved it another way which is: 
`// Takes only digits from distance string and combine them together
                    onlyNumbers = results[j].distance.text.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
                    //Convert string to integer
                    var makeMeInt = parseInt(onlyNumbers);`

I noticed that everything that is not a numerical digit must be removed from the .text for the parseInt to work correctly.

Comment: Did you see my answer for getting the 'value' instead of text (distance.value). Parsing some text looking for a number is not the ideal way to do it...